# GOOGLE ADS API - Click, Cost Conversion Statististics By Country

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I have a problem about writing correct Google Ads API query to get statistics by **country**.

I need to get click, cost, impression and conversion statistics by **country** with Google Ads API.
How should i update my query; does someone have any idea?

```
SELECT metrics.impressions, metrics.clicks, metrics.cost_micros, metrics.conversions 
FROM geographic_view 
WHERE country = 'TR'
```

Comment: Does a `GROUP BY country` works? That's what I would do in normal SQL.

Comment: @Alejandro Thank you; but no. Google ADS API's structure is a little different than default sql queries.